# Notepad ++ How to delete before and after text

Tags: notepad++

output date:

```
<sku>V31L-CPFIJK-11077</sku>
<image1>https://testtest.pl/getled/sku-11077sku-11077.jpg</image1> 
<image2>https://testtest.pl/getled/sku-11077sku-11077,1.jpg</image2>

<sku>V31L-CPFIJK-11033</sku>
<image1>https://testtest.pl/getled/sku-11033sku-11033.jpg</image1> 
<image2>https://testtest.pl/getled/sku-11033sku-11033,1.jpg</image2>
```

Result:

```
  <sku>V31L-CPFIJK-11077</sku>
  <image1>https://testtest.pl/getled/11077.jpg</image1>
  <image2>https://testtest.pl/getled/11077,1.jpg</image2>

  <sku>V31L-CPFIJK-11033</sku>
  <image1>https://testtest.pl/getled/11033.jpg</image1>
  <image2>https://testtest.pl/getled/11033,1.jpg</image2>
```

Does any know have solution how to delete text from img url start from `sku` and end from `sku-`

delete:

```
sku-11033sku-
```

Note: The numbers inside are random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    sku-(\d+)sku-\1
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

[image: Image showing steps]

1. Press **Ctrl + H** to open the *Replace...* dialog box.
2. Enter `sku.*sku-` in *Find what:* and leave *Replace with:* blank. *(`.*` denotes the asterisk (*) wildcard.)*
3. Make sure *Regular expression* is checked under search mode.
4. Hit **Replace All**.

Voila.